# refill JTable from

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I open JDialog from main window to show set of data, retrieved according to parameters and mode.
(in this simplified version parameters doesn't matter, just "Mode", in real I fill it from recordset).I want

1.to fill table in Dialog Window initially

2. optionally use button to show another set of data,  retrieved with different mode

   First mission is OK. Creating table and filling is organised as procedure
   that works properly from dialog constructor.
   But when I run this procedure from ActionListener of button -- I get another copy of table in the same window - it makes sense because I create it once again as "new". I cant find the way I can refill data on the same table! All examples on the net are about creating a new one

Here is calling part

```
btnFreqHistory.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Running history");
                DlgFreqHistory FreqHist= new DlgFreqHistory(1000,2,1 );
                FreqHist.setDefaultCloseOperation(FreqHist.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                FreqHist.setVisible(true);  

            }
        });
```

Here is JDialog part:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTable;


import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class DlgFreqHistory extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();


    static int Freq;
    static int Side;
    static int Mode; //1- last 10 results, 2 - best  results


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public DlgFreqHistory(int iFreq, int iSide, int iMode) {

        Freq = iFreq;
        Side = iSide;
        Mode = iMode;
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setTitle("Last results for " + iFreq  );
        **// !! This call works fine**
        GetHistoryByMode(iFreq, iSide, 2);

            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JButton btn_getData = new JButton("Get data");
                btn_getData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        System.out.println("in action performed");
                        ***// !! This call creates another table***
                        GetHistoryByMode(Freq, Side, 1);
                    }
                }   );

                buttonPane.add(btn_getData);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btn_getData);


    }

    private void GetHistoryByMode(int Freq, int iSide, int Mode)
    {
        System.out.println("in GetHistoryByMode " + Freq + "  " + iSide + "  " + Mode);

        String HistColumns[] = new String[2];
        String HistData[][] = new String[10][2];

        if (Mode==1) { 
            HistColumns[0] = "X1";
            HistColumns[1] =  "Result";
            HistData[0][0] = "xx1";
            HistData[0][1] = "15";
            HistData[1][0] = "xx2";
            HistData[1][1] = "20";

        }
        if (Mode==2) { 
            HistColumns[0] = "Y1";
            HistColumns[1] =  "Result";
            HistData[0][0] = "yy1";
            HistData[0][1] = "15";
            HistData[1][0] = "yy2";
            HistData[1][1] = "23";
        }

        JTable FreqHistory = new JTable(HistData, HistColumns);
        contentPanel.add(FreqHistory);
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane( FreqHistory );
        contentPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't create the `JTable` in the `GetHistoryByMode` method, instead, create it within the constructor and add it to the UI there.  Then in the `GetHistoryByMode` method, create a new `TableModel` and apply it (`setModel`) to the existing `JTable`

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

You might also like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others